# How stop and start the api server instance in kubeadm installed kubernetes? (etcd restore)

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, kubernetes-apiserver

In order to restore an etcd backup the documentation says (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#restoring-an-etcd-cluster):

> stop all API server instances
>
> restore state in all etcd instances
>
> restart all API server instances

How can I do it? Deleting the api server pod will immediately start it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kube API Server runs as static Pod. The manifest of api-server (`kube-apiserver.yaml`) is present in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` directory. Moving this file to a different folder will result in complete termination of api-server pod.

Comment: The details can be found in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/implementation-details/#generate-static-pod-manifests-for-control-plane-components)